# Building SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need some help to build SQL Query. I have table having data like:

```
ID   Date         Value1 Value2 Code
1   12/01/2009     4       3.5     abc
2   12/02/2009     3       4.0     abc
3   11/03/2009     6       8.5     xyz
4   11/01/2009     2       5.5     abc
5   11/02/2009     4       6.0     xyz
6   12/03/2009     5       7.0     xyz
```

I need to show result something like...

```
        ---------
Code   | Data   |    November(Sum of Values in month)      December   Jan   Feb
abc    | Value1 |           2                                 7       0       0
       | Value2 |           5                                 7       0       0
xyz    | Value1 |           10                                5       0       0
       | Value2 |           14                                7       0       0
       ----------
```

I need sum of value in each month as in above data in columns `group by code`.

Comment: Am I right that you want a variable number of columns in your result?

Comment: @Mark; yes for the purpose to display values against each month and show month name in column

Comment: And you want the combined sum of Value1 for xyz from November from all years (you have data from both 2008 and 2009 in your example)?

Comment: @mark, I have edit my quesiton and correct the data, I have set year same, but Fianally I want is if year 2008 Nov and 2009 Nov spereate

Comment: Can you explain how you plan to call the query and how you will display the results? What technologies are you using apart from SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this solution, and let me know what you think.

You have to use both **PIVOT and UNPIVOT** in this instance to get the result you are looking for. Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Date DATETIME,
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 FLOAT,
        Code VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Date,Value1,Value2,Code) SELECT  1,'12/01/2009',4,3,'abc'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Date,Value1,Value2,Code) SELECT  2,'12/02/2009',3,4,'abc'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Date,Value1,Value2,Code) SELECT  3,'11/03/2009',6,8,'xyz'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Date,Value1,Value2,Code) SELECT  4,'11/01/2009',2,5,'abc'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Date,Value1,Value2,Code) SELECT  5,'11/02/2009',4,6,'xyz'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Date,Value1,Value2,Code) SELECT  6,'12/03/2009',5,7,'xyz'


;WITH UnPvt AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  Code,
                            DATENAME(MM, Date) MonthNameVal,
                            SUM(Value1) Value1,
                            SUM(Value2) Value2
                    FROM    (
                                SELECT  Code,
                                        Date,
                                        CAST(Value1 AS FLOAT) Value1,
                                        Value2
                                FROM    @Table
                            ) v
                    GROUP BY    Code,
                                DATENAME(MM, Date)
                ) Sub
        UNPIVOT
                (
                    Vals FOR RowValues IN (Value1, Value2)
                ) AS UnPvt
)
SELECT  *
FROM    UnPvt
PIVOT   (
            SUM(Vals)
            FOR MonthNameVal IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November], [December])
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY Code, RowValues
```

Have a look at

- [SQL SERVER – PIVOT and UNPIVOT Table
  Examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)
- [Give the New PIVOT and UNPIVOT
  Commands in SQL Server 2005 a
  Whirl](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/article/28165)
- [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: No Doubt, you provide always greate solution, I love your solution. Thanks + 100000....... for you...... Again Thanks

Comment: Solution is working perfectly; but could you plz give me somes links that will help me to understand the query; I mean pivot and unpivot used in the query.

Comment: I am getting this error; "The type of column "Value2" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list" because both column have different datatype SUM(Value1) Value1, sum(Value2) Value2; like first have int and 2nd one have decimal/float

Comment: I have Edit the value of value2 column; Thanks

Comment: Changed the answer to CAST Value1 to Float. Have a look.

Comment: Plz check my actual query in the below answer, I am still getting the same above error, Thanks

Comment: Could you plz check my query again below in my posted answer, I am getting last error here when doing.. **Cast((sum(LastYearRevenue)/Sum(LastYearLets)) as Decimal(18,2)) LastYearADR**

Comment: Getting same error  The type of column "LastYearADR" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Comment: Problem is here just.. Cast((sum(LastYearRevenue)/Sum(LastYearLets)) as Decimal(18,2)) LastYearADR other than this every thing working perfectly. just plz check this. What's wrong here. I think I did right.... but.....

Comment: Could you plz check now, I am in trouble right now, many thanks for your help; I have write some description in my query. thanks

Comment: yes, you are right, that's done, I have pasted the final query in my answer at the end... Thanks alot... will not forget your help

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you asked for because the number of columns is fixed, but I think it's a better way to what you want in SQL:

```
SELECT Code, 'Value1' As Data, MONTH(Date) AS Month, YEAR(Date) AS Year, SUM(Value1) AS Sum
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Code, MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date)
UNION ALL
SELECT Code, 'Value2' As Data, MONTH(Date) AS Month, YEAR(Date) AS Year, SUM(Value2) AS Sum
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Code, MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date)
ORDER BY Code, Data, Month, Year
```

Example output:

```
Code Data   Month   Year    Sum
abc  Value1 11  2009    2
abc  Value1 12  2009    7
abc  Value2 11  2009    5
abc  Value2 12  2009    7
xyz  Value1 11  2009    10
xyz  Value1 12  2009    5
xyz  Value2 11  2009    14
xyz  Value2 12  2009    7
```

I'd recommend that you use a bit of non-SQL code to reformat the result into exactly what you asked for before displaying it to the user rather than trying to return a variable number of columns in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to show month name as column and populate data like wise....

Comment: I am using ASP.Net with SQL 2005

Comment: Then it seems fine to me to return the results in the form I showed above and use some simple ASP.NET code to tranpose the results into the columns you want. I'm not sure what the best way of doing this in ASP.NET is, but you might be able to use something like a DataTable to collate the results. You could iterate over the result set and every time you see a month/year combination that you haven't seen before, create a new column in your DataTable for that. Then bind your DataTable to a GridView when you are done. I'm fairly sure that this is easier than trying to write it all in SQL.